# iPhone Add Item/Row Button in Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationbar

Is there a standard way to implement a button like the one below in a navigation bar? If not I can, of course, just use an image or maybe a custom view but as it's used in quite a few apps I thought there may be a method I'm missing.

[image: Add row/item button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barBtnItem;
        [barBtnItem release];
```

this code use for creating + button.

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the standard UIBarButtonSystemItem system icons (`UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd`) - take a look at the `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:target:action:` method in the UIBarButtonItem Class Reference.